# Помощь с replace() и файлами

Tags: python, файловая-система, replace

Не могу понять как это сделать. Т.е я хочу написать программу которая анализирует введённый текст, потом же сверяет со словами в файлах и заменяет,но я не понимаю как это правильно реализовать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```py
file = file.open('маты.txt', 'r')  # файл в котором лежат плохие слова
file = file.read()
txt = file

file1 = file1.open('цензура.txt', 'r')  # файл в котором лежат зацензурные слова
file1 = file1.read()
txt1 = file1

text = input('ах ты дура') #текст
text.replace(txt, txt1) 
print(text)  # должен ввестись 'ах ты дурочка'
```

Comment: Посмотреть в справке как именно нужно использовать replace()

Comment: в файлах позиции слов для замены одни и те же? то есть есть гарантии что файлы имеют одну и ту же длину? в каком виде слова находятся в файлах?

Comment: А если будут слова с орфографическими ошибками или все буквы будут строчные? Как тогда сравнивать будете?